# Iteration of conditional expectation conditioned on independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

This comes from Aad Van der Vaart - Asymptotic statistics, Lemma 11.11 (Hoeffding Decomposition)

Suppose I have independent random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. For any random variables $T$ such that $\mathbb{E}T^2 < \infty$, let $A,B \subset\{ 1,...,n \}$

$\textbf{How do I show that $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(T|X_i:i\in A)|X_i:i \in B) = \mathbb{E}(T|X_i: i \in A\cap B )$ }?$

Comment: To the user who downvoted, please explain why

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\mathbb{E}\left[T \mid X_i: i \in A \right]$ is independent of $X_j$ for all $j \in B \setminus A$.
This ensures that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[T \mid X_i: i \in A \right] \mid X_j: j \in B\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[T \mid X_i: i \in A \right] \mid X_j: j \in B \cap A\right]$$ and using the tower rule is in turn equal to $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[T \mid X_i: i \in B \cap A \right] \mid X_j: j \in A\right]$, now given that $B \cap A \subset A$, $\mathbb{E}\left[T \mid X_i: i \in B \cap A \right]$ is already measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_j: j \in A)$ and we can drop the outer conditional expectation to give the result.

Comment: My struggle is the first equation, which is how do you show equality between the left and right side of $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[T|X_i:i\in A]|X_j:j\in B] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[T|X_i:i\in A]|X_j:j \in B \cap A] $